# Disable 'right-click' on Panasonic CF-H1 digitizer?

Tags: windows-xp, tablet, panasonic-toughbook

A remote user is complaining that their Panasonic CF-H1 tablet is not working.  After additional feedback it was revealed that the digitizer pen's (stylus) right-click button is jammed.  I remember that there is a setting to disable the right-click in Windows XP (via Panasonic Dashboard) but a) don't have a tablet in my office and b) can't find anything in the manual.

How do I disable the right-click of the digitizer pen?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Panasonic Dashboard and enable touch input only.  This will make the stylus "dumb" where it will only point and click.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I have a Panasonic CF-H1.  It's the Health Care Model and every time a patient signed a document on Adobe PDF Annotator and happened to hit the button on the stylus (and sometimes double tapping it) it brought up a right screen.  Very hard to explain the technicalities to them.  I searched and found no answers and finally called Panasonic customer service. That was a joke.  But I DID figure it out.

I'm using Windows 7 Professional.

1. Go to START
2. Type in: "Pen and Touch"
3. Press Enter
4. This will bring you to a dialog box for " Pen and Touch"
5. Under Pen Options - Single tap - Uncheck "Use the pen buttons as a right click option".
6. Under Pen Options - Press and Hold Settings - Uncheck "Enable press and hold for right-clicking"

It did it for me.